# How to delete from multiple tables without cascade? (SQLSERVER T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can delete from multiple tables without cascade?

I would like to delete records from tables `tbInstTypeTestAttribData`, `tbTestAttribData`, `tbInstTypeResultAttribData`, `tbTestResult` and `tbTest` regarding `pki4Test` and `pki4Transfer` matching as FK from `tbDnTestData` and `tbDnReagentData`.

For example instead of using `tbInstTypeTestAttribData.pki4Test =  2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684` I would like to use join etc and use `tbDnTestData.pki4Test =  tbInstTypeTestAttribData.pki4Test AND tbDnTestData.pki4Transfer = tbInstTypeTestAttribData.pki4Transfer`

```
DELETE FROM tbDnTestData where fki4ReagentLot = 201

DELETE FROM tbDnReagentData where pki4ReagentLot = 201

DELETE FROM tbInstTypeTestAttribData WHERE tbInstTypeTestAttribData.pki4Test =  2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684

DELETE FROM tbTestAttribData WHERE tbTestAttribData.pki4Test = 2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684

DELETE FROM tbInstTypeResultAttribData WHERE tbInstTypeResultAttribData.pki4Test = 2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684

DELETE FROM tbTestResult WHERE tbTestResult.pki4Test = 2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684

DELETE FROM [tbTest] WHERE [tbTest].pki4Test = 2226 AND pki4Transfer = 79684
```

Comment: Your statements seem to do that. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: Syntactically the DELETE statements are correct.  They mention not using ON CASCADE.  My best guess is that you are trying to delete data that has a foreign key constraint on it.  If this case, it is either the order of your delete statements or you are not removing all the required data from a table, violating the constraint.  If you are trying to use 1 delete statement to delete data from more than 1 table, you can't.

Comment: @dbbri deletes already working. Question is can we make these more efficient and use join / on etc and not using hard coded numbers like "2226".

Comment: To make the delete statements more efficient look at indexing on the values you are deleting by.  You can create joins in your delete statements but you won't be able to delete from the joined tables.  To remove the hard coded values, create and assign variables.  If there isn't a way to derive the criteria, you could create a config table.  EX: DECLARE @pki4test INT = ( SELECT pkitest FROM [Table] WHERE criteria )